# Isabelle tactic definition

Tags: isabelle

I was trying to copy a tactic file that might help proving my theorem, however, there seems to be having some problems.

The original tactic is like this:

```
fun typechk_step_tac tyrls =
  FIRSTGOAL (test_assume_tac ORELSE' filt_resolve_tac tyrls 4);

(* Output:
Value or constructor (filt_resolve_tac) has not been declared
*)
```

I tried to find this tactic in the internet, but there is not much explanation of this. I saw that some theory file in 2009 use this method, and for 2020 one, a theory file use a similar method called *filt_resolve_from_net_tac*, which I think the types of them are different, so I am not sure about how to use them.

Other than the filt_resolve_tac, the tactic file used a function called *ref* like this:

```
val basictypeinfo = ref([]:thm list);
(* Output:
Value or constructor (ref) has not been declared
*)
```

However, the Isabelle 2020 seems know something about the ref, since when I changed something:

```
val basictypeinfo = [];

fun addT typelist = (basictypeinfo := (typelist @(!basictypeinfo)));

(* It shows error:
Type error in function application.
   Function: ! : 'a ref -> 'a
   Argument: basictypeinfo : 'a list
   Reason: Can't unify 'a ref (*In Basis*) with 'a list (*In Basis*) (Different type constructors)
*)
```

It clearly shows that ref is like a type, and it is defined in the Isabelle right?
Therefore the ref in ref([]:the list) should be similar to a casting function, and I found that there is a thing called *Unsynchronized.ref* which solves the type problem, may I know are they the same thing in this context?

In the later part of the files, there are also some tactic and rule set seems to be not defined, for example:

```
etac: Value or constructor (etac) has not been declared
(*
I saw Prof. Paulson had shown this tactic in his Isabelle lecture, 
but I couldn't find it in the Isabelle manual or the implementation manual, 
is the name of it changed?
*)

ZF_typechecks: I couldn't find any rule sets that has this name in the whole ZF directory.
```

Sorry to have so many questions, it seems that the tactic file is no longer really well-supported by the new Isabelle, are there still people using Isar/ML to define new tactic? Or most people are doing this with the method declaration in the Isabelle? And which part of the Isabelle/Isar reference manual should I read to master this skill? Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Isabelle/ML is still used to define tactics, but this is generally an advanced feature. Depending on what you're doing you may want to look at the Eisbach documentation bundled with the distribution. Also, 2009 is ancient history as far as Isabelle is concerned, those features you're trying to copy are no longer there.